# Org-Mode: Todo state "NEW" not tracked

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to track the state changes of my TODO-items, including the date/time an item was created. I've found out that you can add an exclamation mark while defining the TODO states (e.g. TODO(t!)) and a timestamp should get added. This works when I change the state of a TODO item, but not when it is created (neither via org-capture or manually).

My `org-todo-keywords` definition:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO(t!)" "IN-PROGRESS(i!)" "WAITING(w!)" "|"
                                    "DONE(d!)" "CANCELED(c@)")))
```

I've also enabled logging into the LOGBOOK drawer:

```
(setq org-log-into-drawer t)
```

When I create a new TODO item via org-capture, no LOGBOOK drawer gets added.

Hiere is my capture template configuration:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '(("t" "Task"
                               entry
                               (file+headline org-todo-file "Tasks")
                               "* TODO %^{Description}\n\n%?"
                               :prepend t)
                              ("n" "Note"
                               entry
                               (file+headline org-default-notes-file "Notes")
                               "* %^{Description}\n\n%?\n\n%i")
                              ("l" "Listen"
                               entry
                               (file+headline org-listen-read-watch-file
                                              "Listen")
                               "* %?")
                              ("r" "Read"
                               entry
                               (file+headline org-listen-read-watch-file
                                              "Read")
                               "* %?")
                              ("w" "Watch"
                               entry
                               (file+headline org-listen-read-watch-file
                                              "Watch")
                               "* %?")))))
```

I'm using Spacemacs, btw.

Comment: Have you tried running `org-mode-restart` (or restarting emacs) after modifying `org-todo-keywords`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried restarting Emacs, still the same result.

Comment: I have been using `<%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>` for several years now in my `org-capture-template` to give me the current date when creating an entry.  You can probably just add the time using the same format with the percentage before it.  See the doc-string for the function `format-time-string` for possible entries.